# Objective-C method ':' provided by method ' ' conflicts with optional requirement method ' ' in protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code 
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [Int]` and I want to return an array of `Int` from that method, but I am getting this error

**Objective-C method 'tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:' provided by method 'tableView(*:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'tableView(*:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)' in protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'**

I have tried putting an exclamation mark after `Int` like so `-> [Int]!` but it didn't fix the error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your class seems to implement UITableViewDelegate. The interface UITableViewDelegate does not have a return value for tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: and since your method defines a return type, there is a conflict.

If you remove the return value, so in your case [Int], it should work.
You cannot define multiple methods with the same signature, but with different return values. The signature (method name + parameter) needs to be unique, so you could define methods with the same name and different parameters, but not methods with the same name/parameters and different return types.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Then how would I return something after I have deselected the row? I am sorry if this is a silly question , I am new to Swift and iOS development.

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to return something? You could for example call another method and pass some parameters and do sth with them. And who should receive the return value? tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: is called by the UITableView, so you wouldn't get the return value anyways.

Comment: Well my issue is quite complicated. Basically in that method, I am saving a file to a destination, and I want to be able to read from that file and return an array of ints from that method.